# How to transpiling dart to javascript in Phpstorm

Tags: dart, phpstorm

I installed dart-sdk and downloaded dart plugin to Phpstorm 8.0.3, but I cant figure out how to transpile dart to js. When I am trying to make file watcher I dont have any Dart2Js predefined template in settings.

Thank you

Comment: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/Getting+started+with+Dart

Comment: @LazyOne There is nothing about transpiling dart to js

Answer (score 3):

I know only WebStorm 9 and 10. Maybe you can still derive how it might work in PHPStorm.

Usually you don't want to build to JavaScript on each file change because this would slow your machine down.
During development you use `pub serve` which is automatically launched by WS 9 and 10 and which transpiles Dart files to JavaScript only on demand (when requested by a browser) and only compiles what it didn't compile previously.

For deployment WebStorm can use the `Pub: build ...` context menu of the `pubspec.yaml` file in the project view.

Comment: I've used both PHPStorm and WebStorm for Dart development, and there is really no difference at all (aside from minor changes to the IDE itself since they aren't on identical update schedules). Everything Günter said about WebStorm is true for PHPStorm as well.

Answer (score 2):

See @Günter Zöchbauer answer.
Using dart2js is not the recommended approach, as it runs on file level instead of project, creates output in the src folder, etc. - but the main reason is that it is not clear when/why to use it. If you need to build your project, use `'pub build`' (available in pubspec.yaml right-click menu). When debugging in browser, `'pub serve`' is always used implicitly - it performs all needed transformations... 
But, if you still need this watcher, you can easily configure it yourself by adding a watcher of 'custom' type.

```
Program: path/to/dart2js
Arguments: --out=$FilePath$.js $FilePath$
Working directory: $FileDir$
Output paths: $FileName$.js:$FileName$.js.map:$FileName$.js.deps
```